# is there a way to stop creation of vocabulary in gensim.WikiCorpus when reach 2000000 tokens?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, wikipedia, dump

I downloaded the latest wiki dump multi-stream bz2. I call the WikiCorpus class from gensim corpora and after 90000 document the vocabulary reaches the highest value (2000000 tokens).
I got this in terminal:

keeping 2000000 tokens which were in no less than 0 and no more than 580000 (=100.0%) documents
resulting dictionary: Dictionary(2000000 unique tokens: ['ability', 'able', 'abolish', 'abolition', 'about']...)
adding document #580000 to Dictionary(2000000 unique tokens: ['ability', 'able', 'abolish', 'abolition', 'about']...)

The WikiCorpus class continues to work until the end of the documents in my bz2.
Is there a way to stop it? or to split the bz2 file in a sample?
thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific parameter to cap the number of tokens. But when you use `WikiCorpus.get_texts()`, you don't have to read them all: you can stop at any time.

If, as suggested by another question of yours, you plan to use the article texts for Gensim `Word2Vec` (or a similar model), you don't need the constructor to do its own expensive full-scan vocabulary-discovery. If you supply any dummy object (such as an empty `dict`) as the optional `dictionary` parameter, it'll skip this unnecessary step. EG:

```py
wiki_corpus = WikiCorpus(filename, dictionary={})
```

If you also want to use some truncated version of the full set of articles, I'd suggest manually iterating over just a subset of the articles. For example if the subset will easily fit as a `list` in RAM,  say 50000 articles, that's as simple as:

```py
import itertools
subset_corpus = list(itertools.islice(wiki_corpus, 50000))
```

If you want to create a subset larger than RAM, iterate over the set number of articles, writing their tokenized texts to a scratch text file, one per line. Then use that file as your later input. (By spending the `WikiCorpus` extraction/tokenization effort only once, then reusing the file from disk, this can sometimes offer a performance boost even if you don't need to do it.)